# Bachelor vs Engineer degree and thesis

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity, academia, honorifics, professions

So when it comes to my education I have earned an [Engineer's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineer%27s_degree) at some European university, and my final thesis was some thing that I definitely would like to boast about before my future, potential employer. But while writing my CV I have to this (hopefully) minor confusion. How do I describe this two things - degree and thesis in consistent manner ?

To elaborate, I know that that an Engineer's degree is not really a thing in Anglosphere world and I would be better of describing my degree as a [Bachelor's_degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor%27s_degree) or [Bachelor of Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Engineering). I'm fine with that.
But now what wording should I use for my thesis?
Should it be described as an engineer's thesis or a bachelor's thesis?

My problem with describing it as a "bachelor's thesis" is as follows, in my country there is substantial difference between an bachelor's and a engineer's thesis, the latter consists of not only an thesis itself (the whitepaper) but also comes with some kind of real-live-problem-solution project. So by going with this option, at least as far I understand, I'm omitting piece of crucial, in this case,  information.

On the other hand, if I would like go with "engineer's thesis" it might be little bit confusing for a reader, as there will be two different naming conventions to describe same thing in one document. What is more, I'm not even sure whether this kind of wording will sound right bells in, for example US-based, reader's mind.

How should I approach this ?

Comment: This is a really good question. For the sake of getting more accurate answers, I would advise asking this at the [Academia stack exchange](https://datadigest.psu.edu/student-enrollment/).

Comment: Until you write another thesis in another degree, I don't see the harm in simply calling it "my thesis." To address the accompanying real-world component I might refer to the whole as "my thesis project." At any rate, focus on the merit and content of the work itself, and on the section of the CV listing your education to clarify what degree program you did.

Comment: Just say thesis. And if your degree took more than four years, which is usual, it is not a BA or BS in English.

Comment: Here are a few engineering degree: https://www.infoplease.com/us/education/selected-degree-abbreviations

Comment: Unfortunately, particularly in the UK, real engineering has historically not been given the social and academic status that it deserves and the word 'engineer' is misused frequently to refer to repair men of various descriptions so that you get people who visit customers' homes to repair white goods referred to as 'washing machine engineers'. This bedevils British engineering and is one cause of the skills shortage in the UK. I suspect that there might be a bit of the same problem in the US where the driver of a railroad train is, I understand, called an 'engineer'.referred to as a

Comment: Given that, as you already know, what you are trying to describe has no exact equivalent in English-speaking countries, you should not expect there to be a single word or a short phrase for it. To make it clear what it is, you have to describe it at some length (e.g. 'a degree in engineering that requires the completion of a thesis solving a real-life problem').

Answer (score 1):

First, it's worth noting that *thesis* can be used differently even within the Anglophone world. For instance, one of my colleagues in the UK submitted a *dissertation* for her BA and a *thesis* for her PhD, whereas in the US there are bachelor's and master's *theses* but usually a PhD *dissertation*. The Wikipedia entry on "[Thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis#United_Kingdom)" summarizes many of the concerns.

Otherwise, just saying *thesis* or *my thesis* is valid. In a word search with the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), the most common collocation of *thesis* is *my*, i.e., *my thesis*. Out of nontrivial words, you'll most commonly see "doctoral thesis" or "master['s] thesis" - "bachelor['s] thesis" is actually rare (547 total results for master v. 7 for bachelor). So just referring to the thesis generically will seem less unusual, and you can always elaborate on the format in-text as necessary.

Comment: Bard college (For example) has a *Senior Thesis* project requirement for Bachelor's degrees. This may be the more common wording in the US (?) but the requirement may not be the norm.